# How to properly use null fields in a table (performance wise)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, null

Before I have gone too far into designing the database I wanted to figure out how best to handle this situation.

I currently have a table that is intended to be a bank ledger of sorts. The table has a field for deposits and a field for withdrawls (and a bunch of other information). All of the information in a row is relevant to both deposits and withdrawls however there will only ever be one or the other (deposit/withdrawl) filled in (the other field will always be null).

Should I create two tables (withdrawl table and deposit table) or just leave both defaulting to null and only fill the single value in on insert? That said, is it a performance issue to have null fields like this? And also, what if I were to scale it to include more null fields (say 15 fields in the database. 8 of which would default to null)?

Comment: Could you simply use the sign on a `TransactionAmount` field to determine whether it is a credit or debit? Nullable columns use an additional bit. Bits for multiple nullable columns are packed into bytes, so space isn't much of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

As @HABO recommended I would use one column for amount.  To determine whether it's a withdrawl or deposit create a second column, unless, the sign of the amount is good enough to determine that.  When you want to extract information from the table you could use a view or a calculated column.

If you have your heart set on two separate columns then to ensure that only one is ever set you could add a trigger on the table that enforces that rule and does a rollback if it's violated.  This puts an onus on your middle tier code to enter the data correctly and, of course, react appropriately when the trigger does a rollback and throws a raiserror.